# OpenGL Calculate Matrices

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, matrix, lwjgl

Im trying to switch from the glTranslate etc to my own Matrices, but for some reason it does not work. Here are my 2 functions to create the view- and projection matrix:

```
public Matrix4f getViewMatrix() {
    Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    viewMatrix.setIdentity();
    viewMatrix.translate(game.player.position);
    viewMatrix.rotate(game.player.rotation.x, new Vector3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    viewMatrix.rotate(game.player.rotation.y, new Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    viewMatrix.rotate(game.player.rotation.z, new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    //System.out.println(viewMatrix);
    return viewMatrix;
}

public Matrix4f getProjectionMatrix() {
    FloatBuffer projectionBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    GL11.glGetFloat(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, projectionBuffer);
    Matrix4f projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    projectionMatrix.load(projectionBuffer);
    return projectionMatrix;
}
```

I send those 2 matrices to the Vertex shader with a uniform, and use:

```
gl_Position = view_matrix * proj_matrix * vec4(in_position, 1.0);
```

Where in_position is the coordinate of the vertex.

I do see some things on the screen, but it's very, very buggy, and nothing is right about it.
If I use the build-in gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix in the shader and use glTranslate and glRotate in OpenGL, it works perfectly fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the output of me view projection together with the camera position:

```
0.5095141 0.0 -0.8604623 1.1625774
0.7321221 0.52541286 0.43351877 16.980185
0.45209795 -0.8508474 0.26770526 0.8665553
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0

Vector3f[1.1625774, 16.980185, 0.8665553]
```

Comment: Try (proj_matrix * view_matrix) * vec4(in_position, 1.0);

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'd suggest attaching your generated matrices so we can tell whether it's your generation, uploading, shader, etc

Comment: That didn't work. I added the output of the View matrix in the post.

Comment: wait, why do you have GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX in getProjectionMatrix()? Should be GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX

Comment: Your right. I fixed it, but I still see the weird flippy things on my screen.

Comment: In getViewMatrix(), you translate before you rotate. Which is going to cause your rotations to be different than intended.

Comment: Also true, still kinda the same result though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it seemed that my projection matrix was completely wrong. Here is my new version which works great:

```
public Matrix4f getProjectionMatrix() {
    // Setup projection matrix
    Matrix4f projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    float fieldOfView = 40.0f;
    float aspectRatio = (float)Display.getWidth() / (float)Display.getHeight();
    float near_plane = 0.1f;
    float far_plane = 1000f;

    float y_scale = coTangent((float) Math.toRadians(fieldOfView / 2f));
    float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;
    float frustum_length = far_plane - near_plane;

    projectionMatrix.m00 = x_scale;
    projectionMatrix.m11 = y_scale;
    projectionMatrix.m22 = -((far_plane + near_plane) / frustum_length);
    projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
    projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * near_plane * far_plane) / frustum_length);
    projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;
    return projectionMatrix;
}
```